# Wordpress not opening posts with only numbers if permalink is post_name

Tags: posts, permalinks, urls, get-posts, title

Someone knows why this happens?

For instance, I have a post called `1987`, but it does not open it when I click on the link. When I use a different permalink structure, it opens it. Why is this and how can I solve this?

FYI: **I don't get a** `404 error`, I just get a Firefox error where it says: **this page is not redirecting it well**

Comment: this might have something to do with the date archive rewrite rule- WordPress thinks your numeric post name is a request for a date archive for the year 1987

Comment: Alright... Is that in htaccess? What do I have to do to solve it?

Comment: Tentatively confirmed. Have you looked in [trac](http://trac.wordpress.org) to see if this is a know issue?

Comment: No, but I did now... Can't see what to do actually. Is there a solution for this or not?

Comment: The problem involve only 1 post? If so, once I had the same problem and solved appending '_' to the slug (not touching title, of course). I know it's not a really solution, but it's easy to do and it works.

Comment: I know, but it's about a couple of posts, so that won't work.

Comment: This may take some effort to figure out. I'd bet that it does have something to do with date archives rewrites, as suggested by @Milo. If that is the case it is a bug in Core and possibly a difficult one. That is why I asked if you had searched Trac.

Comment: Ah, alright. So I detected a bug. Nice, but too bad that it isn't fixed until this time :P Thanks guys!

Comment: Do you use date archives on your site? You could change the structure of the date archive links to be prefixed with something, like `/date/`, then they'll no longer clash with your post links. I'm pretty sure I've actually answered a similar question before with this solution now that I think about it. I'll try to dig up that previous answer if that's something you'd want to do.

Comment: I am not using date archives. Is there a setting for that? I am not using it is my thought, but if it's activated somehow, I don't know. How can I shut that off?

Comment: Trac topics related to this are: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5305 and: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13701

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I didn't follow up on this. You mentioned you weren't using date archives. You can change the date archive structure to remove the conflict with `/%postname%/`:

```
function wpa_change_date_structure(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->date_structure = 'date/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%';
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_change_date_structure' );
```

So now after permalinks are flushed, date archive URLs will be prefixed with `date/`, so numeric postnames will no longer match the date rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by updating the post's slug to something besides a number.  Other than that, I haven't found a solution (while still keeping post-name as the permalink).

Comment: my answer might work for you